# memmem in linux kernel source

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Inside a kernel module, I need a memmem-like function (find a needle in a haystack given both lengths), but I can't find one. I know the kernel implements [strnstr](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-strnstr.html) but I need to work on binary data. So I just copied the code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/string/memmem.c) to implement it in the module, but I was wondering if I overlooked something. It seems weird that the kernel does not implement such a function itself.

Comment: Kernel only implements stuff submitted by contributors. If nobody needed `memmem` before, then it would not be there. There's no some standard, like Posix, which mandates which functions should or should not be present in the kernel.

Comment: searching is not popular in kernel code because it is slow.